# Do I have to use 'due to the fact' or 'by the fact'

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

Could someone please tell me whether I have to use 'due to' or 'by' in the following phrase?

> This tone is mainly created due to/by the fact that the video contains real footage of wars and attacks on aid workers.

Comment: Which ever construction you prefer, it's a mouthful of a sentence. There's no need for **the fact that**. All it needs is: **The tone is mainly created by the (real)(video) footage of wars and attacks on aid workers.**

Comment: “the fact that” is nearly always better omitted: *This tone is created mainly by the real footage …*

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean the first.  Neither is wrong, but their meanings slightly differ:

> This tone is mainly created by the fact that the video contains real footage of wars and attacks on aid workers.

^  This is correct use and sounds natural.  It means that the "fact" was the thing that created the "tone".

> This tone is mainly created due to the fact that the video contains real footage of wars and attacks on aid workers.

^  This is a little bit awkward, but not incorrect.  It means that the "tone" was created indirectly because of the "fact".  A different person, place, or thing (perhaps an unspecified and default, natural, or automatic process) actually creates it.

If you meant that the footage creates the tone, use the first.